# VBA Data Validation List Selection

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a code to embed in one table. The situation is like this:
Cell A1 (with option of 50,100 and 150) and cell A2 (with option of 1000 and 5000), both have data validation list in them. When I choose cell A1 of 50, A2 has to be 1000. When I wrote the code and made the selection, there is always an error:

> Run-time error '-2147417848(80010108)': Method 'Add' of object 'Validation' failed.

Please share your opinions or if need I post my codes here to resolve this issue.

The basic code is as following:

```
Select Case Range("A1").Value
Case "50"
         Range("A2").ClearContents
        Range("A6").Value2 = "1000"

Case "`100"
         Range("A2").ClearContents
       With Range("A2").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
        :=xlBetween
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
        Range("A2").Value2 = 1000
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow.  You need to give more information.  How about posting the code you wrote.

Comment: The following is the code: Select Range("A1").Value   Case 50, Range("A2").Value=1000 End Selection    I thought it should be a easy code, but in the excel workbook, when I choose 50 in A1, there is an error and my excel crushed,

Comment: Do you know about debugging VBA code.  If not find out.  You need to quote the error given to you.  Does your code compile.  What module is your code in.

Comment: Hi I edited my post. I debugged but the info poped out is not enough for me to solve. I use the change mode in VBE.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do now....See my answer.  In future try to give as much information and explanation as possible.  People can't help you much otherwose!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to the module of the sheet with the cells you want validation added to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then

        If Target.Value = 50 Then

             Range("A2") = 1000

            ' Add valid values of 1000 allowed only
            With Range("A2").Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="1000"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid value"
                .ShowInput = False
                .ShowError = True
            End With

        Else
            ' Add valid values of 1000 and 5000 allowed
            With Range("A2").Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="1000,5000"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid value"
                .ShowInput = False
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        End If




    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi friend. It did work! Thank you so much! But do you know which part I'm wrong? Your code is very useful but  for this part "If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then" what's the difference between "A1" and "$A$1". and can you explain a little bit for me? Thanks again,